# Для чего нужен магический метод __path__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для чего нужен магический метод `__path__`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699287/what-is-path-useful-for)

Если вы измените `__path__`, вы можете заставить интерпретатор искать в другом каталоге модули, принадлежащие этому пакету.

Это позволит вам, например, загружать разные версии одного и того же модуля в зависимости от условий выполнения. Вы можете сделать это, если хотите использовать разные реализации одной и той же функциональности на разных платформах.

Comment: Было бы не плохо показать на примере.